# Error in AndroidManifest.xml File of an Android Project With Default Values

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I currently deal with a tutorial for beginners to build my first Android application in Eclipse. I created a new Android project with default values. Next, Eclipse reports an error in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file. Here is the line producing the error:

`android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"`

This is the error message: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'icon' with value '@drawable/ic_launcher').

How do I fix this?

Comment: Excerpt of the [Manifest documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html) concerning `android:icon`: This attribute must be set as a reference to a drawable resource containing the image (for example "@drawable/icon"). _There is no default icon._

Answer (score 4):

Change `ic_launcher` to the name of the icon which is located in your `project/res/drawable/` folder

This is a common error in Android. At some point, the Android new Project Wizard changed the default name it would give to the application icon (and some tutorials are still using the old name).

Please read more about [Android fundamentals](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fundamentals.html), so you can figure out how things are organized. A drawable is a resource. Resources are located in the res/ folder (although, resources are indexed in a R file which is automatically generated before everything gets compiled).

Comment: Thanks! There are no icons in the folders, so is there a way to go about creating them in Eclipse?

Comment: That's weird, not even in the other drawable- folders? Yes, do File > New Android Project... You can even make them here online: http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/icons-launcher.html#foreground.space.trim=1&foreground.space.pad=0&foreColor=33b5e5%2C0&crop=0&backgroundShape=bevel&backColor=ffffff%2C100

Comment: @user1953907 Yep, there should be a wizard under New -> Drawable or something like that.

Comment: Ya It is strange. I deleted the project and went through it again. The icons show up in the preview, but when I create the project, they are in none of the drawable folders. I have no idea what could be happening.

Comment: May be they're there, but Eclipse doesn't show them to you because of the Eclipse Explorer View you're in? Like I said, they're probably there, but they probably have the wrong name (therefore your code doesn't find them). Either that, or I'm wrong. Try creating them manually.

Comment: @StephanBranczyk I tried doing that. I did not change anything and just kept the defaults. It still did not show up in the drawable folders (any of them). One thing that may be the problem is that my workspace is in a folder on the desktop (so not in the same folder as Eclipse) I have no idea if this could do something. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure you're looking at the right folder (and not the original project folder you imported and copied into your Eclipse workspace)? If you're sure, make sure all your Android tools and SDKs are up-to-date (using your SDK Manager). Make sure Eclipse is up-to-date too. Restart the entire machine once. If things don't work, re-install Eclipse ADT Bundle from scratch all over again (if still nothing, try installing Android Studio Preview and tools instead). I don't know what else to tell you. If you have a friend who knows Android, bring your laptop to him/her to show him what's going on.

Comment: If things still don't work, you should note your OS, your version of Eclipse, and research your problem on StackOverflow. If you can't solve your problem that way, you should start another completely new question describing your problem in detail, specifying version numbers, telling us the version number of your JDK (not just your JRE), and posting a screenshot of what Eclipse lets you see after having created an Android Application project (reset the Eclipse perspective and reopened the Eclipse Android/Java perspective).

Answer (score 2):

What it is saying is that there is no file `drawable/ic_launcher`. To fix this, simply create a drawable named `ic_launcher`.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing "ic_launcher" in your draw able files, simply add one or remove the line of code.